# EF Core Primary key check through exception handling

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to insert new entries into a database without verifying that the entry already exists through a separate query (e.g. a get query etc).
I have something similar to the code below and it seems like that even though I am changing the entry.Id (PK) I am not able to successfully insert the entry
since the entity is still tracked as EntityState.Added, even though the add failed due to an exception.
My goal is to reduce the database requests to a minimum and I would like to prevent a primary key check before inserting. The primary keys are already predefined and not incremented by the Db itself.

```
public void InsertObject(DbContext dbContext, Entry entry) {
    while (!Add(dbContext, entry)) {
        entry.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}

public bool Add(DbContext dbContext, Entry entry) {
    try {
        dbContext.EntryTable.Add(entry);
        return true;
    } catch (DbUpdateException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: your primary key is indexed, at least it should be. So the query is really fast and entity framework has it's own caching and optimisations - is it worth it ?

Comment: Postgres provides 2 possible (depending on version) processes for this. The first is with [Insert ... on colflict ...](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html), the second (available with v15 or greater) is the [Merge](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html) statement. Of course there is always handling the exception thrown when a duplicate occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Business logic by exception will potentially be less performant than a simple index check. (`dbContext.EntryTable.Any(x => x.Id == entry.Id);`) The business logic itself should ensure that Add is only ever called with a non-existing "entry", where the database is responsible for ensuring every new entry is provided a unique ID. (Identity column rather than `Guid.New()` in code)

That said, if you do persist with exception-based logic then you can detach the newly tracked instance:

```
public bool Add(DbContext dbContext, Entry entry) 
{
    try {
        dbContext.EntryTable.Add(entry);
        return true;
    } catch (DbUpdateException ex) {
        dbContext.Entry(entry).State = EntityState.Detached;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that if you are dealing with more complex entity structures you may need to dive through the entity graph to detach child entities as well.